# Reference request Singular Integrals

Tags: reference-request, singular-integrals

Does anybody know a good book to study singular integrals other than Professor Stein’s one? I want to study this topic but could not find a good PDF of professor Steins Book and I cannot buy it right now (it is almost 100$ at amazon).

If somebody give me some more suggestion would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I like Grafakos's "Classical Fourier Analysis". From looking at the table of contents in Stein's book, I think they have a decent amount of intersection. (They also would be a second version: "Moderne Fourier Analysis" of Grafako's, I didn't look into that yet though).